# Compare means of two groups with a variable that has multiple sub-group

Tags: statistical-significance, spss, experiment-design, mean

I was unable to understand how to compare multiple mean values in each group. Within the subgroup the mean values influence each other (If one changes, the other changes automatically).

I collected travel distance and the mode of transportation choice at two different locations. There are 32 people in each location with "x" different modes. A person can choose one mode and record their travel distance.

How should I compare to see if the travel distances traveled by different modes of these two groups are significantly different? If it is categorical data, I know I have to use chi square, but does the t-test work here? I believe the t-test is to compare two groups with one mean in each group. But I have 2x separate mean values (one for the each mode and two locations).

Answer (score 2):

You should neither use chi-squared (which is suitable for frequency data) nor t-test (which is meant to compare two means).

Here your measure is numerical scale data (not just count) and you have two factors and one possible interaction:

- Location (two levels)
- Mode of transportation (more than two...)
- And the interaction of both.

What you should try to do is an ANOVA (you have to check some assumption related to the nature of your data [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance#Summary_of_assumptions)).

That will allow to study the effect of location and mode independently and optionally how each factor impact the effect of the other (that is the interaction).